# How to download and install gradle android plugin completely offline?

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to install android studio on a machine with no internet connectivity. i can only download files on another computer and transfer it via usb to the offline machine.
i mangaed to install android studio with gradle tool but i can't find a place where i can download the gradle android plugin and use it in gradle.build script.
any ideas?

I tried searching in gradle plugin repo but couldn't find any match.

Comment: Have you tried to go into offline mode on one device and copy whole AS folder?

Comment: Download and execute everything of the computer with Internet connectivity and then capture the project folder and most important the folder `.gradle` in your home directory.